# Different Protocols with Email Client and WebMail

Tags: email, smtp

Can someone tell me if I have covered all Email protocols when using an Email client and Web Mail to send and receive email?

**Email client:**

POP        -Receiving an email;
IMAP       -Receiving an email;
SMTP       -Connecting to Mail Server (Sending an email);
SMTP Relay -Connecting directly to Mail Relay Server (Sending an email);

**Web Mail**

HTTP       -Receiving / Reading emails;
SMTP       -Sending an email

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague and depending on the exact formulation there may be more (or less) protocols involved. 
For example you likely need DNS services to lookup the domain names and for example TCP/IP and Ethernet or similar for the transport.

Also note that SMTP Relay isn't an extra protocol and HTTP is not a Protocol that deals with emails, so unless the question asks for these specifically, you want to scratch those.

Comment: Thanks Max what would be a better label that would include SMTP Relay and HTTP with IMAP, POP and SMTP - interfaces perhaps?

Comment: REad http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc821 and you will see that there is no SMTP Relay protocol it's just part of the SMTP protocol.
You could try to include HTTP with the others by asking for the Application layer protocols in the sending and receiving of emails via a desktop and a web client, but that would still at least include DNS

Comment: thanks for the answer Max, I'll go with 'interface' applied to either an email desktop client or web-mail client to get out of including DNS ;)